# Concerned about skin tags

Tags: dogs, diet, skin-condition

I have noticed the second "skin tag" on my (adult) dog. I pet, stroke and massage my dog regularly and these seem to pop up suddenly - out of nowhere. They resemble rice and appear to be fatty skin. They seem harmless enough and are not in an area that bothers her. Still... it concerns me.

Has anyone had similar issues or inquired about it with a veterinarian?

Update: the rice-shaped skin tag has fallen off. What's up with that?

Comment: Could you add a picture of such a tag to your question? And how does it feel? Hard, soft, dry, oily? Do they only appear in one particular place or anywhere? One at a time or many at once?

Comment: This is her second one. It feels like a human skin tag, kind of mushy but retains the shape of a rice grain. She has had one on her side, and one on the back of her ear. Each at seperate times over the last 8 months. The first one (on her side) I removed accidentally. This recent one (on her ear) came off without my knowledge - either through her scratching, or her collar scraping it off, or in playtime with other dogs. Not sure when or how. Too late for pictures though. (No blood with either tag)

Answer (score 1):

My Bichon gets these all the time. I took her to the vet for her first couple but they confirmed it's nothing to worry about. My vet said that some of hers were warts whereas others were skin tags and they were likely to get more frequent as my dog ages. Both of these are non-hazardous and simply cosmetic which is a relief.

I'm not saying you shouldn't take your dog to the vet, if you're concerned then there's nothing like the peace of mind their advice can give you. This is just my experience from your description of the bumps.

**[This website](https://www.avodermnatural.com/blog/decoding-bumps-skin-tags-on-dogs)** provides fantastic information on lumps and bumps on your canine if you're looking for more specific information and images to identify them.

Answer (score 0):

We have a Shih Tzu and he has skin tags as well.  Our vet said it's common and nothing to worry about.  You never know though... I would ask the vet next time you're in.

petcarerx.com is another resource for info.